# Editable select/combobox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

is there any way (or plugin) to display editable combobox? I have a set of options, but I would like to give possibility to enter custom value.
I've searched the documentation, and I can't find way to do this. I made workaround with javascript, but I'm looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: The conventional solution to this is a regular text field with autocomplete - there's a ton of javascript plugins to do this, eg the jQueryUI autocomplete.  I don't think you could have a combo of select and textfield without js.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that there simply is no HTML form element that does this, and so Rails can't provide you with a helper. As you said, you can work with JS to create something similar (and there should be JS libraries/plugins already out there), or you could just use a select element and add a text field next to it for new values.

Answer (score 1):

[HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/spec.html#contents) doesn't define such an element. So you may either continue using JS, either try to use [autocomplete feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-autocomplete-attribute) of an `input` element (although it is not exactly what you want and doesn't compatible with old browsers).

Comment: Ok, I was just thinking there is existing rails/formtastic plugin, which allows to do that. I found some js solutions, but can't find any which fits my requirements, so I decided to write custom solution.